# Undergrad GPA: Will a C affect grad program application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, undergraduate, gpa

I am currently in a public university (top 50 nationally, top 10 among public schools) for undergrad (3rd year), double majoring in operations research and economics. The past quarter I took 5 major courses because two of them were easy, and I ended up with 3 A's, an A- and a C. The C is a core math upper level course (real analysis serial B, about Riemann integral and Jordan regions) and the reason that I got the C is because of the professor's harsh policy that nearly 80% of students received C or worse grades. I planned to apply for master programs next year, and I am not pretty sure is that C a big problem to me? I am interested in master programs like applied economics, business analytics or finance.  My GPA overall now is 3.43 with operations research overall 3.2 and Econ 3.6. This is the first C on my transcript. Thanks!

Comment: A lot depends on what your other upper level *math* grades look like.

Comment: @aparente001 I only took 5 upper math courses until now, with others A, A- B+ and B.

Comment: What were the other four courses, what order did you take them in, and what was the grade for each one?  Any discernable trends are helpful, and since math learning builds on itself in certain course sequences, this would be helpful information.  So far the specifics you shared in your question look encouraging.

Comment: @aparente001 Took Abstract Algebra last quarter got B+ and Real Analysis I for B, and this quarter, Real Analysis II for C, Probability for A and Combinatorics for A-. Next quarter I have also three major math courses, Optimization, Mathematical Finance (an enrichment) and Stochastic Process. This quarter's other two Econ courses are enrichments of my math major and got A+ and A for them (Corporate Finance and Econometrics).

Comment: I suppose an admissions committee might think that perhaps your major strengths don't lie in Real Analysis (B for part I, C for part II).  Can you figure out which of the courses you plan to take will rely heavily on what you learned in Real Analysis?  An advisor or mentor might be able to help you figure that out.  If your future studies won't depend much on that subject matter, then you could let it be water under the bridge.  Otherwise, it might be helpful to zero in on those topics to get more solid on, for your own benefit.

Comment: @aparente001 I think I will not take any courses rely on Real Analysis. My math major requires some applied math courses, like optimization and data mining. Also Econ in undergrad does not need analysis skills. The analysis courses are mandatory to every math department students. So, what you mean is that if I apply for a grad program which does not require analysis skill, then the negative effect of I did badly in analysis may bot be so significant?

Comment: Right, if you can show strengths in the areas that will be important.  However, watch out, some optimization courses can be rather hairy, mathematically!  At any rate, as a grad student, you and your advisor will evaluate your skills, your strengths and any deficiencies you may have, and will figure out a game plan for how to remedy any deficiencies.  Grad school is very self-driven, very individualized.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for your comments! Gonna try my best to do well in the following quarters!

Comment: Happy studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". However, depending on the school you're applying at, they may use a holistic approach to your application, meaning the C could have a small negative impact. However, if it came down between you and another candidate and you're the one that has the C, the other candidate will most likely get accepted.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask for some suggestions about what I should do next to neutralize that negative effect? For example like doing well in the next two quarters (before application)? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: @CanLiang The obvious answer is get all A's :) but in all seriousness, I would start to show interest in applied econ, business analytics, or finance outside of school. If it's applied econ, maybe do research with the World Bank. If it's business analytics, maybe learn SQL and do an internship that uses that. If it's finance, do something finance related.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was okay on the track, since last quarter I did pretty well in the hardest econometrics course with the professor's promise of a strong recommendation letter, some undergrad research experiences in Econ and mastered the usage of a data analysis software. That should be the track. Also I will try my best to get as high grades as possible for my remaining courses. Thanks for your comments and suggestions!